# Android save the user input in a several fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I want to save the user input of several fragments, i try with the method onSaveInstanceState to save the state and the method onActivityCreated to restore the data, my source is:

```
package com.example.recepcionauto.app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 *
 */
public class Cliente extends Fragment {


    private EditText txtRut;
    String rut = null;

    public Cliente() { }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
        if (savedState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            rut = savedState.getString("rut");
            txtRut = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtRut);
            txtRut.setText(rut);
            Log.v("Log", "Recuperando del Bundle");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("rut", rut);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.v("Log", "Guardando en el Bundle");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause( ) {
        Bundle outState = new Bundle( );
        outState.putString("rut", rut);
        super.onPause();
        Log.v("Log", "Se ejecuto onPause( )");
    }
}
```

this is my activity, is a view with listview and fragmentlayout

```
package com.autocastillo.recepcionauto.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Principal extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView lvMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lvMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMenu);

        List<String> lmenu = new ArrayList<String>();
        lmenu.add("Cliente");
        lmenu.add("Vehiculo");
        lmenu.add("Conductor");
        lmenu.add("Accesorios");
        lmenu.add("Resumen");

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment startFragment = new Cliente( );
        transaction.add(R.id.myFragment,startFragment);
        transaction.commit();


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lmenu );
        lvMenu.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                //Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "You Clicked at " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Fragment newFragment=null;

                switch (i){
                    case 0:{
                        //Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Cliente " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        newFragment = new Cliente( );
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1:{
                        newFragment = new Vehiculo( );
                        break;
                    }
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment,newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

                Log.v("Prueba", "llamo a itemclick");
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.v("Log", "Guardando en el Bundle");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
    }

}
```

What is wrong?, the onSaveInstanceState not work, i try with putSerialize and nothing, please i appreciate your cooperation

Comment: Why do you want to save state? onSaveInstance state is not called on all occasions. Mostly I use it just for screen rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to save is the Fragment state as is, take a look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446961/when-to-use-fragmentmanagerputfragment-and-getfragment), which is more an explanation than an example. You should be using the [`putFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#putFragment(android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.Fragment)) and [`getFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragment(android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)) methods from your `getSupportFragmentManager()` instance.

I recognize I've been a little late using these two bad boys on my own, but they're quite useful. Let me give you a hint on where to add them:

#### putFragment

Inside your `Principal` activity, add this directly in your `onSaveInstanceState` method. One call per fragment you want to save:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Cliente fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "cliente", fragment);
}
```

#### getFragment

You can (and should, actually) use `getFragment` inside the `onCreate`. Use the already passed `savedInstanceState` variable, and slightly change the way you init the fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
Fragment startFragment = null;
if(savedInstanceState == null) { // first open
    startFragment = new Cliente( );
} else { // rotation, change where the fragment was already there
    startFragment = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "cliente");
}

transaction.add(R.id.myFragment,startFragment);
transaction.commit();
```