# How to reuse layout set in setContentView? Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, android-configchanges

I am trying to use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in my Manifest so that I cannot lose state of my `VideoView` when configuration changes happen. This means I need to choose the layouts myself on the configuration. The problem I am having is that when I first initialize which view to use in `onCreate`, here:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video_land);

        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video);
        }
}
```

It chooses the right layout. But when I need to adjust the layout on the configuration change like here:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video_land);
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video);
        }


    }
```

It does not use the same instance of the layout, but rather reloads it, which makes my `VideoView` go black. Then I am unable to press any buttons after that.

Is there a way to reuse the initial layouts? I have tried to set the views like this one `setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video_land);` to an `Activity activity` object, but IDE won't let me, it says `Activity is incompatible with void`. Because if I could get a reference to that view, then I could reuse it. Or is there a simpler way of doing this that I am not seeing?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kushal suggestion, I looked into the 2 methods of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to save my `VideoView` state on configuration change (since this was the root of my problem, and using `setContentView` was just a hack idea). Turns out I found some code out there. Here is what I did:

1. Make sure I had a landscape `xml` and a regular `xml`. In my `layout-land` and `layout` folder respectively with the same name.
2. Overrode those 2 methods like this:

   ```
   private int position = 0;

   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
       // use onSaveInstanceState in order to store the video
       // playback position for orientation change
       savedInstanceState.putInt("Position",  videoView.getCurrentPosition());
       videoView.pause();
   }

   @Override
   public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
       // use onRestoreInstanceState in order to play the video playback
       // from the stored position
       position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
       videoView.seekTo(position);
   }
   ```
3. Took the `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` out of my Manifest.
4. Deleted the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method (didn't need it anymore with #3 gone).

This did it! I was able to change orientation at anytime, and record my video at anytime. Upon returning from recoding the video, it would easily display in either landscape or portrait, without losing the video (screen never went black).

The only problem I have now is my `OnTouchListener` is disabled, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting alternative and simple solution for your problem :

> **1.** Move layout activity_make_photo_video_land to /res/layout-land/ folder and rename it as activity_make_photo_video.xml
>
> This way your activity_make_photo_video_land view (rename as
>   activity_make_photo_video) will be inflated when orientation changes
>   to LANDSCAPE

So, you are not required to handle these facility manually from java code.

Change the onCreate() to :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video_land);

}
```

Your application will have single layout activity_make_photo_video in **/res/layout/** and **/res/layout-land/** both folder

**UPDATE** :

> Unless you specify otherwise, a configuration change (such as a change
>   in screen orientation, language, input devices, etc) will cause your
>   current activity to be destroyed, going through the normal activity
>   lifecycle process of onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() as
>   appropriate. If the activity had been in the foreground or visible to
>   the user, once onDestroy() is called in that instance then a new
>   instance of the activity will be created, with whatever
>   savedInstanceState the previous instance had generated from
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

Override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and save your state here

You can check more [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

I hope this will work

Comment: Thanks, that won't work though. The whole reason I need to do it manually is to try to save the state of my `VideoView`. Letting Android choose my layouts when I go back and forth to/from landscape/portrait means the `Activity` gets restarted, and hence I lose my loaded video. Plus, any layout I put in `layout` folder forces portrait. And any layout I put in `layout-land` forces landscape, no matter what they're named.

Comment: I don't entirely understand, but you can't put an object in a Bundle: "... you can't put plain object in a Bundle.  And the reason for this is that the point of that saved state is for it to be copied out of your process, so if your process needs to be killed, it can later be copied back in to a new process for you to re-initialize your activity/fragment from. A raw object is only meaningful in the context of the process it is running in, so it isn't possible to correctly copy the reference to such an object out of your current process and in to another."

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446961/when-to-use-fragmentmanagerputfragment-and-getfragment/6542596#6542596).

Comment: If you know of a working example that's simple, let me know. I don't see how it would look in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Kushal, I was able to find some code out there, very lucky. I managed to override those 2 methods. I can't mark your answer correctly, since there were a lot of different things I changed, but your answer pointed me in the write direction, so thank you! I wrote details in another answer, to keep a log for others.