# In the Activity onSaveInstanceState () inside Bundle to save data appears strange?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Activity inside viewpage, I have to set up the adapter, and save the data, the code is probably as follows:

```
List <Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList <> ();
mFragments.add (AFragment);
mFragments.add (BFragment);
mFragments.add (CFragment);
```

`onSaveInstanceState ()` inside the code below:

```
bundle.putSerializable ("key", (Serializable) mFragments);
```

This time I switch the screen orientation `onSaveInstanceState` method call, whether it is saving data or restore data are normal.

But I am now in the interior of A, B, C just a fragment starts the camera to take pictures, that they will report Parcel: unable to marshal value `AFragment {6afa2b}` this error. After lookup is calling `onSaveInstanceState()` inside `bundle.putSerializable ("key", (Serializable) mFragments);` sentence being given.

I do not know why not? Great god who seek help ah.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` does not implement `Serializable`.  If you need to persist a `Fragment`, use [FragmentManager.putFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#putFragment(android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.Fragment)), you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446961/when-to-use-fragmentmanagerputfragment-and-getfragment).